# conditional expression in one line if statment

Tags: python

`self.values` is optional parameter (List) in my class.

I have the following code:

```
self.values.append(area) if self.values else self.values = [area]
```

This produce

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to conditional expression
```

I know I can fix this by doing:

```
 if self.values:
    self.values.append(area)
 else:
    self.values = [area]
```

But isn't there a shorter way to set it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following, using the fact as it the list is `None` or empty, it's evaluated as false and the other operand of the `OR` expression will be used

```
self.values = (self.values or []) + [area]
```

Comment: Honestly, I think I would still prefer the if statement alternative. This feels like a little bit of mental gymnastics. Would refactor a little though `if self.values is None: self.values = []` and then `self.values.append(area)`